# Where can i find the digest for my docker image so I can delete it from the Registry?

Tags: docker-registry

### Update

After reading the documentation a few more times, I realized I'b been looking in the wrong place for the digest. It is NOT in the manifest.

If you do a HEAD or GET on the v2/name/manifests/tag you will get a header (Docker-Content-Digest) which contains the digest:

```
Server  nginx
Date    Sat, 02 Nov 2019 19:01:16 GMT
Content-Type    application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v1+prettyjws
Content-Length  2839
Connection  keep-alive
Docker-Content-Digest   sha256:fcb864bea187b2efbf23d1032052461170fcb482e2dd99f9db5f9a8b538e553d
Docker-Distribution-Api-Version registry/2.0
```

Depending on the version of your Registry (or may be unrelated to that), the inclusion of a specific header at the time of sending GET or HEAD will cause a different digest to be returned.

This header is:

```
Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
```

Even though the version of Registry that I'm dealing with is 2.0 inclusion of this header causes a different value to be returned for `Docker-Content-Digest`

Anyways, I tried both variations and I'm still not able to delete each time getting

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "DIGEST_INVALID",
            "message": "provided digest did not match uploaded content"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's a link to the documenation in case someone's interested in it:

https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/

### Original

I have the following manifest which is downloaded for my image. I have tried every string here in place of the Digest but I have not been able to do that.

Could someone point out which one of these is the digest that i need for a Delete command?

I am using a DELETE http request with the following formulation:

```
https://my_registry.com/v2/demo/derivedimage/manifests/<whatever the digest is supposed to be here>
```

This is the error I get every time:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "DIGEST_INVALID",
            "message": "provided digest did not match uploaded content"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 1,
   "name": "demo/derivedimage",
   "tag": "4c3a6f78fe709a098a0d24a2c43639e7e170bc5981004554a154245662fea132",
   "architecture": "amd64",
   "fsLayers": [
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
      },
      {
         "blobSum": "sha256:0f8c40e1270f10d085dda8ce12b7c5b17cd808f055df5a7222f54837ca0feae0"
      }
   ],
   "history": [
      {
         "v1Compatibility": "{\"architecture\":\"amd64\",\"config\":{\"Hostname\":\"\",\"Domainname\":\"\",\"User\":\"\",\"AttachStdin\":false,\"AttachStdout\":false,\"AttachStderr\":false,\"Tty\":false,\"OpenStdin\":false,\"StdinOnce\":false,\"Env\":[\"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\"],\"Cmd\":[\"sh\"],\"ArgsEscaped\":true,\"Image\":\"sha256:02cc0eb9e9d093c512e57d613a9c1d89b0b50b551bbed33e3116459e7d15ee7e\",\"Volumes\":null,\"WorkingDir\":\"\",\"Entrypoint\":null,\"OnBuild\":null,\"Labels\":null},\"container\":\"e24c19c10096d9b60b9ac2276cc24ec9a1ab93e8330dff511362b8e983a4e040\",\"container_config\":{\"Hostname\":\"e24c19c10096\",\"Domainname\":\"\",\"User\":\"\",\"AttachStdin\":false,\"AttachStdout\":false,\"AttachStderr\":false,\"Tty\":false,\"OpenStdin\":false,\"StdinOnce\":false,\"Env\":[\"PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin\"],\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh\",\"-c\",\"#(nop) \",\"CMD [\\\"sh\\\"]\"],\"ArgsEscaped\":true,\"Image\":\"sha256:02cc0eb9e9d093c512e57d613a9c1d89b0b50b551bbed33e3116459e7d15ee7e\",\"Volumes\":null,\"WorkingDir\":\"\",\"Entrypoint\":null,\"OnBuild\":null,\"Labels\":{}},\"created\":\"2019-10-30T23:20:37.206592274Z\",\"docker_version\":\"18.06.1-ce\",\"id\":\"d624e6ec746cd764114cfd7f4ab1fb0852e670c10df15adb1e75b4f99e4123be\",\"os\":\"linux\",\"parent\":\"9f31ac69fd90b9035252a2e1bac45e3d43b7d32316be7e4ac7a737d9d11b092b\",\"throwaway\":true}"
      },
      {
         "v1Compatibility": "{\"id\":\"9f31ac69fd90b9035252a2e1bac45e3d43b7d32316be7e4ac7a737d9d11b092b\",\"created\":\"2019-10-30T23:20:37.083008444Z\",\"container_config\":{\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:1141b81e5149cc37c4346ee17e282cca8c7016a9bcfeb7a54842a87ecf8419d4 in / \"]}}"
      }
   ],
   "signatures": [
      {
         "header": {
            "jwk": {
               "crv": "P-256",
               "kid": "3NQM:K5YD:M3XF:EKJD:4S64:3772:BJOT:JIMR:NX4R:2XYS:IDNA:NOKL",
               "kty": "EC",
               "x": "k6pZfyr-dKYLri5KJCL70UmNLCQnfUh2lAC_nDK9PVw",
               "y": "MhrKOUbx1sgsbF0kG9d5bfvkVaxaFWiKlWTwgFyHkbQ"
            },
            "alg": "ES256"
         },
         "signature": "0TWLKZlltDA4kQJR4orhg7NenglG2OevQMSaN-RXCwFod7cyO5VFLVEeBDvsFhuAsvsw8mO475g1G9bW_Zh-aA",
         "protected": "eyJmb3JtYXRMZW5ndGgiOjIxOTIsImZvcm1hdFRhaWwiOiJDbjAiLCJ0aW1lIjoiMjAxOS0xMS0wMVQwNDowMTowNloifQ"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Instead of saying "I have tried every ...", show one example with all details exactly as you are executing and the error. Most likely the problem is very simple.

Comment: Do you know specifically which one of those numbers is the digest? Or are you just guessing I am doing something wrong? If you know one, i'd be glad to try it and send you the full transcript

Comment: Since you have not posted an actual example, I am just guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is how the digest is sent. In my case, I had to include the header:

```
Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json
```

to get the right digest in the incoming header `Docker-Content-Digest`

Second I had to include the "sha256:" in the outgoing digest. Example:

```
curl -vk -X DELETE https://my_registry.com/v2/demo/derivedimage/manifests/sha256:679b1c1058c1f2dc59a3ee70eed986a88811c0205c8ceea57cec5f22d2c3fbb1
```

And the reponse is:

```
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
```